# Remove comma from author - biblatex

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber

I have using `biblatex` package and want to remove comma in the author. How to do this.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-ibid,sorting=nyt,dashed=false]{biblatex}

@ARTICLE{ipab730bbib2,
    author ={S F Edwards},
    year =1967,
    title ={Statistical mechanics with topological constraints: I},
    journaltitle ={Proc. Phys. Soc.},
    volume={91},
    pages={513},
}
```

I am expecting result is `Edwards S F` only. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The punctuation between family and given name in family-given order is controlled by `\revsdnamepunct`, which defaults to a comma. If you don't want that comma, just redefine `\revsdnamepunct` to be empty.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  dashed=false,
  terseinits, giveninits
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{ipab730bbib2,
  author       = {S. F. Edwards},
  year         = 1967,
  title        = {Statistical Mechanics With Topological Constraints: I},
  journaltitle = {Proc. Phys. Soc.},
  volume       = {91},
  pages        = {513},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ipab730bbib2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Edwards SF (1967). ‘Statistical Mechanics With Topological Constraints: I’. In: Proc. Phys. Soc. 91, p. 513.]

---

If you want to retain the space between the initials and only want no dots, remove the `terseinits` option and add

```
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}
```

to the preamble.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  dashed=false,
  giveninits
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{ipab730bbib2,
  author       = {S. F. Edwards},
  year         = 1967,
  title        = {Statistical Mechanics With Topological Constraints: I},
  journaltitle = {Proc. Phys. Soc.},
  volume       = {91},
  pages        = {513},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ipab730bbib2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Edwards S F (1967). ‘Statistical Mechanics With Topological Constraints: I’. In: Proc. Phys. Soc. 91, p. 513.]

Comment: It's working fine. But space is missing. It should be `Edwards S F`. In the bib file space is found but output space is missing. How to get with space?

Comment: @Balaji Oh, sorry I thought you wanted to remove the space. The question said `Edwards SF`.

Comment: I am sorry and modified the question now.

Comment: @Balaji I see. Have a look at the edit, please.

Comment: But in the end of the initials comma is present. `Edwards S F,` it should be `Edwards S F`. How can modify this?

Comment: @Balaji I get no comma after the name in the code from my answer. Neither with the complete code that I posted nor with `terseinits` removed and `\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}` added. Please post a complete example document that reproduces the undesirable output you get.

Comment: sorry it's working fine. The same above question how to remove dot when using year (example: year=2015). or can i post separate question?

Comment: @Balaji Yes, that would be a separate question. When you post your question, please consider posting a compilable example (like the one in this answer) and not just a short excerpt of the preamble.